# How to specify routing tables on Android devices via tun

Tags: android, tun

### Device

- Rooted Android 10

---

I compiled the Zerotier-One CLI myself via NDK and was able to run it on Android and access ZT's virtual network with the egress NIC specified (e.g. `ping -I ztyvvzal2p 10.0.1.100`)

Now, I want to be able to access the IP of ZT's network with the routing table specifying ZT's virtual NIC, just like Linux

---

When I don't specify the NIC, the packet is sent to the eth0 NIC by default. When I check the routing table, everything is fine.

```bash
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5a:4c:16:a6:b4:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:ef:00:1c:c2:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.13/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ztyvvzal2p: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 2800 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:77:44:f3:bb:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.68/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global ztyvvzal2p
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip route show
10.0.1.0/24 dev ztyvvzal2p proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.68
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.13

# tracepath -n 10.0.1.100
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  10.10.10.1                                            0.929ms
 1:  10.10.10.1                                            0.988ms
 2:  10.10.10.1                                            1.010ms pmtu 1480
```

So I tried using `iptables`

```bash
# Option A
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.1.0/24 -o ztyvvzal2p -j ACCEPT

# Option B
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ztyvvzal2p -d 10.0.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.1.68
```

Neither option A nor option B has any effect, for packets from the ZT segment are still sent to `eth0`

Am I missing something?

What should I do to get the routing table to take effect?